# How to show from which country / city the last login was made?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a problem that I will never be able to solve on my own, I hope someone will help me here, thank you for any answers and I appreciate any help.

Basically I have two functions, one sets the date of the last login and current login, while the other gets the login set by the first function. With simple shortcodes I can then display the date of the last login and current login. This works well, but in addition to the dates I also want to show the location from which the login was made and which browser was used.

### Geolocation Function

So to do this I wrote a geolocation function that returns lat and long value, with reverse geocoding I then get the readable address. This also works well.

### Get Browser Function

Then I wrote another little function that gets the browser used by the user with user agent, this also works wonderfully.

### Main Problem

The problem with geolocation and get browser is that functions always return current values. But that's not what I want.
What I want to do is store locations and browsers at login (just like I do with dates) and then view them. In this way, if you log in at point A at 00:00, this will remain the same. Currently it does not do this because it is only hovering where you are at the moment and not where you were at 00:00.

So how can I memorize locations and browsers just like I am doing with dates? I specify that I am working on my website with wordpress.

**Date function**

```
// Function that get last login
function get_last_login($user_id, $prev = null) {
  $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id);
  $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
  if(isset($last_login['_last_login_prev'][0]) && $prev) {
  $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, '_last_login_prev', 'true' );
  } 
  else if(isset($last_login['_last_login'][0])) {
    $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, '_last_login', 'true' );
  } 
  else {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_last_login', $time );
    $last_login = $last_login['_last_login'][0];
  } return $last_login;
}

// Shortcode (1) - Last Login Date 
function last_login_date() {
  global $current_user;
  echo '<div class="lastlogin"> '.date("j/m/Y - H:i", get_last_login($current_user->ID, true)).' </div>';
}   add_shortcode('lastlogin', 'last_login_date');

// Shortcode (2) - Current Login Date
function current_login_date() {
  global $current_user;
   echo '<p>Current: Login date: '. date("j M Y - H:i", get_last_login($current_user->ID)). '</p>';
}   add_shortcode('currentlogin', 'current_login_date');
```

**Geolocation function**

```
//enqueue my-script
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'woocommerce/myaccount/assets/my-script.js', array( 'jquery-min' ), wp_get_theme()->version, true );

//pass ajax and a nonce to my-script
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'localize', array(
  '_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
  '_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( '_ajax_nonce' ),
));

add_action( 'wp_ajax__wpso_73934145', function () {

  if ( check_ajax_referer( '_ajax_nonce' ) ) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
    $openStreetMapObject = $_POST['openStreetMapObject'];
    $meta_key = '_user_position';
    $meta_value = array(
        'latitude' => $latitude,
        'longitude' => $longitude,
        'openStreetMapObject' => $openStreetMapObject,
    );

    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    wp_send_json_success( $meta_value );

  } else {

    wp_send_json_error();

  };

  wp_die();

});
```

**my-script.js (for geolocation function)**

```
console.log( 'my-script.js has been successfully loaded' );

if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( position ) {

        let lat = position.coords.latitude;
        let lon = position.coords.longitude;

        //https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/
        $.getJSON(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`, function( object ) {
            
            let adress = object.address;
            
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: localize._ajax_url,
                data: {
                    _ajax_nonce: localize._ajax_nonce,
                    action: '_wpso_73934145',
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: lon,
                    openStreetMapObject: adress,
                },
                success: function ( response ) {
                    console.log( response.data );
                },
            } );
        } );
    } );
};
```

**my-template.php (to view everything).**

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
              $meta_key = '_user_position';
              
              if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user_id, $meta_key ) ) {
        
                $meta_value = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true);
                //var_dump( $meta_value );
                //var_dump( $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']["ISO3166-2-lvl6"] );
                //echo $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']['county'];
                //echo $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']['country'];
                //var_dump( $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']['city_district'] );
                //echo $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']['city_district'] ;

                $mybrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";
                $browser = get_browser(null, true);
                
                $mybrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                if (strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "opr/")) {
                    // OPERA
                    $mybrowsername="Opera";
                } else if (strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "chrome/")) {
                    // CHROME
                    $mybrowsername="Chrome";
                } else if (strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "msie")) {
                    // INTERNET EXPLORER
                    $mybrowsername="Internet Explorer";
                } else if (strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "firefox/")) {
                    // FIREFOX
                    $mybrowsername="Firefox";
                } else if (strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "opr/")==false and strpos(strtolower($mybrowser), "chrome/")==false) {
                    // SAFARI
                    $mybrowsername="Safari";
                } else {
                    // OUT OF DATA
                    $mybrowsername="OUT OF DATA";
                };
                echo $mybrowsername;
                echo $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']['county'];
                echo $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']['country'];
                echo $meta_value['openStreetMapObject']["ISO3166-2-lvl6"];
   
              } else {
                echo 'You need to share your location';
              };
```

Comment: You can leave it to third party APIs. ```$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]``` will give you the IP address and you can just cURL from PHP and get the WHOIS info(Location, country) of that IP address in JSON response.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I am quite new to this, if you like could you please write an example answer?

Comment: As I understand, you don't know how to store the last login location? One option is to store customer IP in database after customer has logged in and then retrieve it from database. This hook is executed after login https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm relatively new to php and wordpress. How can I store the position with the hook and then return it with echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your current code cannot work with what you're trying to achieve, you need to save a login activity everytime a user perform a login which includes all the details you want to pull later.

**Here is a full example.**

**1.** modify the login form and add two hidden input fields for `latitude` and `longitude` from `navigator.geolocation` which you can do via [login_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_form/) action hook

```
add_action('login_form', function() {
  ?> 
  <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude" />
  <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" />
  <script>
    if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => {

        const latitude = document.getElementById('latitude') // get the latitude input field
        const longitude = document.getElementById('longitude') // get the longitude input field
        latitude.value = position.coords.latitude  // assign the latitude input value
        longitude.value = position.coords.longitude //  assign the longitude input value

      })
    }
  </script>
  <?php
});
```

**2.** Process all the data you want to pull later and save it on user meta once the user successfully login, you can inject it via [wp_login](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/) action hook

```
add_action('wp_login', function( $uname, $user) {

  $limit = 5; // the activity limit you want to save

  $lat = $_REQUEST['latitude']; // get the latitude value from the login request
  $long = $_REQUEST['longitude']; // get the longitude value from the login request

  $browser = detectBrowser(); // generate browser data based on user agent

  //generate location if latitude and longitude is present. Otherwise, use the user ip to generate the location
  $location = $lat && $long && getLatLongLocation($lat, $long)->address ? getLatLongLocation($lat, $long)->address : getIPLocation();
  
  $date = date('j/m/Y - H:i');

  // Format the data to be saved as login activity
  $loginDetails = [
    'date' => $date,
    'browser' => [
      'ua' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      'name' => ( isset( $browser->client ) && isset($browser->client->name) ) ? $browser->client->name : '',
      'device_type' => ( isset( $browser->device ) && isset($browser->device->type) ) ? $browser->device->type : '',
      'os' => ( isset( $browser->os ) && isset($browser->os->name) ) ? $browser->os->name : '',
    ],
    'location' => [
      'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
      'city' =>  isset( $location->city ) ? $location->city : '',
      'country' =>  isset( $location->country ) ? $location->country : '',
      'lat' => $lat,
      'long' => $long
    ]
  ];

  $logins = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_login_activity', true); //  get the user meta that holds the login activities
  $logins = $logins ? $logins : []; // pass empty array if the user meta does not contain anything yet
  array_unshift($logins, $loginDetails); // push the recent $loginDetails to the top of the login activities array

  //Save the login activities, only save the array from 0 to $limit position
  update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_login_activity', array_slice($logins, 0, $limit) );

}, 10, 2);
```

the above code you uses the following functions that request to 3rd party APIs to get the data;

```
// Get location details from IP address
function getIPLocation( $ip = false) {
  $ip = $ip ? $ip : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
  return $details;
}

// Get location details from latitude and longitude
function getLatLongLocation( $lat = false, $long = false) {
  if ( !$lat || !$long ) 
    return;
  $query = "format=json&lat=$lat&lon=$long&limit=1&email=test@email.com";
  $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?$query"));
  return $details;
}

// Get browser details from user-agent
function detectBrowser( $ua = false ) {
  $ua = $ua ? $ua : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $ua = urlencode( $ua);
  $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.apicagent.com/?ua={$ua}"));
  return $details;
}
```

You can check the output of these function by simply dumping the output like;

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {

  $latLongLocation = getLatLongLocation('lat-here', 'long-here');
  $ipLocation = getIPLocation('ip-here');
  $uaDetails = detectBrowser('user-agent-here');

  echo '<pre>', print_r($latLongLocation, 1), '</pre>';
  echo '<pre>', print_r($ipLocation, 1), '</pre>';
  echo '<pre>', print_r($uaDetails, 1), '</pre>';
});
```

After, you've added the modification for `login_form` and `wp_login` action hook, there should be a user meta with a key `_login_activity` everytime a user perform a login.

Now you can simply create a function to pull the value and display anywhere you want.

First, a function to format the HTML output for invidiual login record

```
// display format for individual login activity
function logFormat( $log ) {
  if ( !$log || !is_array( $log ) )
    return;

  return '<div class="login-activity">
    <div>Date: '.$log['date'].'</div>
    <div>Browser: '.$log['browser']['name'].'</div>
    <div>OS: '.$log['browser']['os'].'</div>
    <div>City: '.$log['location']['city'].'</div>
    <div>Country: '.$log['location']['country'].'</div>
    <div>IP: '.$log['location']['ip'].'</div>
  </div>';
}
```

then a function to get all or a single specific login record

```
// Pull the login activity with dynamic position attribute
function getLoginActivity( $atts ) {

  //exit function of user is not logged
  if ( !get_current_user_id() )
    return;

  // get the current user meta
  $logins = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), '_login_activity', true);

  //add shortcode attribute support
  $attr = shortcode_atts([
        'position' => 'all'
  ], $atts );

  if ( !isset( $logins[0] ) )
    return 'No Login Activity';
  
  // Output all login activity if position is left to default
  if ($attr['position'] === 'all' ) {
    $out = '<div class="all-logins">';
    foreach( $logins as $login ) {
      $out .= logFormat( $login );
    }
    return $out. '</div>';
  }

  //return the login activity with exact position
  if ( isset( $logins[ (int) $attr['position'] ] ) )
    return logFormat( $logins[ (int) $attr['position'] ] );
  
  return 'No activity with position: '. $attr['position'];
}
add_shortcode('login-activity', 'getLoginActivity'); // add shortcode support
```

then you can simply use `getLoginActivity` function anywhere in your php file, the current login details should be the `0` position and previous last login details should be the `1` position

so you can simply do

```
echo getLoginActivity(['position' => '0']); // current login data
echo getLoginActivity(['position' => '1']); // last login data
echo getLoginActivity(); // all login data
```

or via shortcode added to a page

```
[login-activity position="0"]
```